# Modal popup in master page only showing in 1 page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

I have a script that will end a user's session for inactivity. SO basically if the user is inactive for a certain period of time a pop up comes up asking them if they want to continue the session. I put the code in the master file and when I login and go to the home page the popup comes up and everything works as expected. But when I navigate away from the home page it doesn't pop up and the session ends after inactivity without asking the user if they want to continue the session.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="aPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aPopupLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-close="60" data-open="240">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Inactivity Warning</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have been inactive for at least 4 minutes. Click on Close if you want to continue.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="closed">Close</button>
                <span class="will-close">will be closed after : <strong>n</strong> seconds</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the js

```
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var idleInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var closeSeconds = $("#aPopup").attr("data-close");
        
        if(idleTime > closeSeconds){
            ShowPopup();
            idleTime = 0;
        }
        else { 
            idleTime++;
        }
    }, 1000); 

    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function ShowPopup() {
    var popup = $('#aPopup');
    var time = $(".will-close strong");
    var closeSeconds = $("#aPopup").attr("data-close");
    var openSeconds = $("#aPopup").attr("data-open");

    setTimeout(function(e) {
        popup.modal('show');
        time.html(closeSeconds);

        interval = setInterval(function() {
            time.html(closeSeconds);
            closeSeconds--;

            if (closeSeconds < 0 && !closed) {
                popup.modal('hide');
                clearInterval(interval);
                LoggingOut();
            }
        },
        1000);

    }, openSeconds * 1000);
}

$(document).on('click', '#closed', function(evt)
{
    var full = location.protocol+'//'+location.host;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.href,
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
    clearInterval(interval);
    ShowPopup();
});

function LoggingOut() {
    var full = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: full + "/LogoutService.asmx/LogOut",
        success: function(response) {
            location.replace(full + "/Account/Login");
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone please tell me why this popup is only showing on the home page after logging in and then it doesn't show up on other pages but the session still ends as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Might be an obvious question but: are you including both the modal HTML and the script in all pages? And also (again obvious): are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No just the master page. I don't see any console errors also. The weird part is that it is working on my other application without any issues. Popup shows up on all pages.

Comment: You've tagged this with C# so I assume asp.NET? Because I'm not too familiar with that. If you are including the modal only on the master page, does it mean its HTML will still appear on all pages? Did you check the source code? (Ctrl+U) Also try `console.log($('#aPopup').length)` which should show `1`.

Comment: Yes it is .NET. The console.log($('#aPopup').length) is coming as 0. Also is there a way to make sure this popup happens only when the user is not logged in? All the pages are using the same master page.

Comment: Why would a "your session is about to end" popup only appear to users that aren't logged in? Anyway, did you look at the source code yet? Including a chunk of HTML on all pages sounds like an extremely trivial thing to do and I have no idea how your project is set up, how asp.NET templating works or what most likely the error is you made. Sorry.